# Facebook and twitter integration with my android application

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

I saw some topics here regarding facebook and twitter integration with Android Application.

I need help regarding, is twitter integration with Android App possible in real??
[I need to tweet on user's wall and all]

If i wanted to integrate Facebook with my App then whether i go as per explained in following link(and if this is the recommended way then how to implement this SDK):

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=146956

or

else i use Android facebook SDK available here on code.google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official facebook SDK for android is here:

http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/

It includes complete examples of use.

> > I need help regarding, is twitter integration with Android App possible in real?? [I need to tweet on user's wall and all]

In real? Of course! You could be able to tweet on the user's **timeline**. In this case, use the appropiate authentication methods. There are many ways to do so, this is one of them:

http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/24/index.html

You can also use specialized third-party libraries (like twitter4j) to use Twitter from your Android app.

Comment: Hi Cristian thanks for responding immediately, it is really helpful and can u tell me is it possible to autologin(or communicate with these two sites w/o asking user to login) each and every time user starts my App in Facebook and Twitter so that user can tweet and/or post on his wall

Comment: Yes, that's possible, just take a look at the examples.

Comment: Hey Cristian i implemented FB that way it is working fine thanks, now see the scenario i have a page where i have to ask user whether he would like to share facebook info with my app there is checkBox and in that page if user clicks next with checked CheckBox than automatically facebook window open ups OR i have to open it up onClick of Facebook button? Thanks in advance.